# Translating js to C#

Tags: javascript, c#, unity-game-engine

Need assistance with translating JS to C#.

Original script:

```
var target : GameObject;
var fadeDuration : float = 3.0;


function Update(){

    if (target.GetComponent.<Renderer>().material.color.a > 0)
    target.GetComponent.<Renderer>().material.color.a -= Time.deltaTime/fadeDuration;
}
```

Translated C# script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class FadeOutDeadBody : MonoBehaviour {
GameObject target;
float fadeDuration = 3.0f;
void Update (){

    if (target.GetComponent.<Renderer>().material.color.a > 0)
    target.GetComponent.<Renderer>().material.color.a -= Time.deltaTime/fadeDuration;
}

}
```

I receive errors from Unity3d that say:

> folder/FadeOutDeadBody.cs(9,29): error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `<',
>   expecting`identifier'

Any ideas how to fix this problem?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because StackOverflow isn't a coding service

Comment: Disagree, it's a valid question with a demonstrated effort to solve before coming here for help.

Comment: Then it's a quality issue or he should open a new question, not off-topic.

Answer (score 6):

Just delete your dot in `GetComponent.<Renderer>`
=> `GetComponent<Renderer>`

Comment: Done that. Now it says:

FadeOutDeadBody.cs(10,46): error CS1612: Cannot modify a value type return value of `UnityEngine.Material.color'. Consider storing the value in a temporary variable

Comment: you should follow what @Cody said for the next, it should works

Answer (score 5):

Everyone left this out so I decided to post.

You cannot modify the alpha of a `color` directly. You have to create a new `color`, modify the alpha, then assign it back to your `Material` color. Also remove the dot too. This is what it should look like:

```
public class FadeOutDeadBody : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject target;
    float fadeDuration = 3.0f;

    Renderer renderer;

    void Start()
    {
        renderer = target.GetComponent<Renderer>();
    }

    void Update()
    {

        if (renderer.material.color.a > 0)
        {
            Color color = renderer.material.color;
            color.a -= Time.deltaTime / fadeDuration;
            renderer.material.color = color;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer works, but you should save the Renderer from the first call instead of using `GetComponent<Renderer>()` twice.  GetComponent is a slow operation so you'll find performance benefits from avoiding calls like `GetComponent`, `FindGameObject`, `FindGameObjectsWithTag`, etc as much as possible.

Comment: Ah, I see you edited that away right after I typed out that comment

Comment: @Cody Provided the answer quickly so that I will do that later on instead of doing it when there is a duplicate answer. Yes I did :)

Comment: Thank you Cody, seems like its all working but now I get this error:

NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
FadeOutDeadBody.Update () (at Assets/TestLevel/BEAST/FadeOutDeadBody.cs:19)

Comment: Make` target` public then make sure to assign the target from the Editor. Look at the updated code. I just made it a public variable. Drag the the target gameobject to the target slot.

Comment: @berdyev I can't tell what line 19 is, especially because I don't know if you used my or Programmer's code.  I'm guessing his comment answers your issue though.

Comment: @berdyev if Programmer's comment doesn't answer it, you can always do `target = GameObject.Find("name of game object here");`, which may be necessary if the object you are searching for is Instantiated instead of existing in the scene at compile time.  Don't call that during Update though or it'll hurt your performance.

Answer (score 3):

`GetComponent.<Renderer>()` -> `GetComponent<Renderer>()`
You have extra '.' in there that is throwing the compiler off.

Edit to respond to your comment on romain-aga's answer

You need to expand it to look something like this (C# works a bit differently than JS so you can't be as flexible)

```
Renderer r = target.GetComponent<Renderer>();
Color c = r.material.color;
c.a -= Time.deltaTime/fadeDuration;
r.material.color = c;
```

The r, g, b, and a properties of a color in C# are read-only, so you have to modify the entire color value.

Note: I don't have Unity on the computer I'm at right now, so this is untested.  We'll see how well my memory is working today.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of this

```
target.GetComponent.<Renderer>()
```

you probably need this

```
target.GetComponentInParent<Renderer>()
```

or this

```
target.GetComponent(typeof(Renderer))
```

Comment: FadeOutDeadBody.cs(10,12): error CS1061: Type `UnityEngine.GameObject' does not contain a definition for `target' and no extension method `target' of type `UnityEngine.GameObject' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: FadeOutDeadBody.cs(10,54): error CS1612: Cannot modify a value type return value of `UnityEngine.Material.color'. Consider storing the value in a temporary variable

Answer (score 2):

Just be careful when "translating" code from one language to another, as conventions are language specific. Looking at the unity docs, the proper way to call `GetComponent` is as a generic, so you can fix this particular issue by simply removing the period in your code calling GetComponent.

In general, you will probably have more problems like this due to C# being very different from JavaScript, so just be aware of this.

Reference: [GetComponent documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.GetComponent.html)

Comment: Thanks bud! Ill check it out!